# How long is the animation of the transition between views on a UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, caanimation

Ideally, there would be some kind of constant containing this value.

I'm implementing code that has it's own transition animations, and I'd like those to have the same length as the platform transition animations.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's no constant containing this value. However, using the following `UINavigationControllerDelegate` methods:

```
- (void) navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    startTime = [[NSDate date] retain];
}

- (void) navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"Duration %f", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate: startTime]);
}
```

... I can see that the duration is approx 0.35 seconds

Interestingly, different parts of the views take different times to transition into place. See this great blog post for more details:

http://www.iclarified.com/12396/a-closer-look-at-iphone-transition-animations

Comment: On iOS 8 the animation duration appears to be `0.2` seconds. (There is now a constant you can refer to:`UINavigationControllerHideShowBarDuration`.)

Comment: This comment should be an answer, it's helped me many many times

Comment: This constant only applies to the animation of navigation BARS, not the viewController views themselves.

Comment: The timing of `UINavigationController.hideShowBarDuration` appears to be faster than the push/pop animation.

Answer (score 27):

In **iOS 7** and later you can have exact value by setting the `UINavigationController` delegate and using the method:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
      willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                    animated:(BOOL)animated {
    NSTimeInterval duration = [viewController.transitionCoordinator transitionDuration];
}
```

This is future proof method if the defult duration will ever change. At the moment it's value is 0.35 second.